# C++ Break omp parallel for

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

This is a part of my prime hunter. I want to break the omp parallel for as soon as possible just after the condition met and the b set to false:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for( long l = 1; l <= n; l++ ) {
if (m % p[l] == 0) {
b = false;
*// Break omp parallel for*}
}
```

I tried to achive this by do loop but I couldn't figure it out. Can anybody modify this for me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only way is to add a failure variable, but it won't give you any performance boost;

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for( long l = 1; l <= n; l++ ) {
    if (b) {
        if (m % p[l] == 0) {
            b = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Better would probably be to split the loop into segments, if it's really going to be that long;

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for( long l = 1; l < n / 2; l++ ) {
    if (m % p[l] == 0) {
        b = false;
    }
}
if (b) {
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for( long l = n / 2; l <= n; l++ ) {
        if (m % p[l] == 0) {
            b = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Simply split it into as many as you think is best.

For a more complex answer which uses manual threading (but allows `break`ing), see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9813239/1180785

Comment: Also I'm not sure that your l variable is correct; are you sure it should be 1-based not 0-based? And is this a prime number calculator by any chance?

Comment: Yes, I tried the same with your first suggestion by do loop. But it is still waiting for to finish 'l's regardless if the condition(failure variable) met or not. I saw the same article but it is very complex for my level to follow out what is going on there...

Comment: Essentially the other answer splits the parallel for into its component parts; a thread split and loops on each. It's not as good as the built-in functionality, but in a case like this the disadvantages won't be noticeable. The first suggestion I made won't give you any benefit, no (I said as much above it); it would only be useful if your loop body had more complexity. I think the second block of code is a good compromise for you; pretty easy to understand and will avoid most of the waiting if you split it correctly.

Comment: I have one of the very shortest (but not the fastest) codes for a prime hunter, Dave. If you like I can post it to you in private.  It is a trick to reduce iteration time. m starts from 1 and goes like +=2, not like m++. It's because there is no even prime other than 2. So I am looking for only odd numbers thus I am not looking for the divisibility with 2. That was why.

Comment: (For the second approach): Actually, splitting to two seem enough for me. But I did notice no difference in terms of time.

Comment: But my original code consist of two nested loops and it is not suitable for MP. I am seeking an alternative to make it favorable for Mp. Thats why I add a stupid boolean there instead of some other function. I thing I'll give up. I bet that my original code is one of the best for single thread for finding nth prime.

Comment: I took that as a challenge and made my own! http://codepad.org/us9IetCT It's pretty short, by no means the fastest, but it's quite elegant and doesn't do anything silly.

Comment: @user2002000 Updated to be shorter, faster, uglified, fixed a mistake http://codepad.org/nYC1ON99 (I'm not going to get anything done for a while!)

Comment: Ok, check this one then: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?714443-Finding-nth-prime. If there were a computer with an ultimate clock speed, this would be the best one.

Comment: "It's pretty short, by no means the fastest, but it's quite elegant and doesn't do anything silly" I can tell the same. Elegant is very assertive but ı can say it, too...

Comment: @user2002000 cool. You might want to add the check for `p[l]*p[l] > m`; it's a common way to cut the search right down. I added profiling to mine, but I don't think it works on this online tool: http://codepad.org/U2TMC2f7

Comment: @ Dave Thanks :) I didn't get `p[l]*p[l] > m;` part. Exactly where and how? I think it omits the squares of primes but how to do this?

Comment: @user2002000 It's just a quick way to exit the loop. If you get beyond sqrt(m), you know nothing after that point will match unless something before it also does (think about it). Also, I just realised that this can be done in 3 lines of code; http://codepad.org/dTayI1Nj I think I'm done now!

Comment: @ Dave Aaa!! you updated my code in a more professional way :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: The code works OK. The only problem is ,t doesn't work for 1. Because it doesn't allow you 0 size array. Also something can be done to omit multipliers of 5 for i.

Comment: @user2002000 then add a special case for 1 that doesn't run that code. Why would you want to calculate the first 1 prime numbers anyway?!

Comment: http://codepad.org/Q53DmVGD how about something like this? It prints two 2 but works fine with C++.Net.

Comment: It's slower that way, because you're now checking if every number is a multiple of 2 when you already know it isn't. Often faster code is *longer* than slower code; I only made it that tiny because it was an interesting challenge (and I tried to keep it as fast as possible). Anyway this comment thread is far too long. If you're interested in optimisations like this, I suggest you search or start a new question.

Comment: Yes you are right. I set `j=1` already but may be it is not the right move. I am not that good with programing but maths. Even I couldn't solve what had you done totally yet. Thanks for accepting me. If you have time this is my email address mertener@gmail.com Please, tell what you have done step by step because there are things such as `unlikely` of which I don't know but guess what it is doing. Thanks a lot again ;)