# Parallel OpenMP loop with continue as a break alternative

Tags: c++, openmp, break

I'm referring to this question: [Parallel OpenMP loop with break statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793791/parallel-openmp-loop-with-break-statement)

The code suggested here:

```c++
volatile bool flag=false;

#pragma omp parallel for shared(flag)
for(int i=0; i<=100000; ++i)
{    
    if(flag) continue;
    if(element[i] ...)
    {
          ...
          flag=true;
    }
}
```

What are the advantages of using `continue`? Is it faster than doing the following:

```c++
volatile bool flag=false;

#pragma omp parallel for shared(flag)
for(int i=0; i<=100000; ++i)
{    
    if(!flag)
    {
        if(element[i] ...)
        {
              ...
              flag=true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I could imagine that the first implementation could be favored on stylistic grounds as people tend to find "flatter" code, i.e. fewer levels of indentation, easier to read.

Comment: Alternatively use a `taskgroup` and have `cancel taskgroup`.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout AFAICT cancellation depends on the `OMP_CANCELLATION=true` environment variable; you can't enable it within the program. Besides, you can use `#pragma omp cancel for` and not define any `taskgroup`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After compilation, they are identical at least for the trivial case.

[Without continue](https://godbolt.org/z/aoMnY1jsr)

[With Continue](https://godbolt.org/z/nWMv7hfP6)

If you compare the resulting assembly there is no difference between the two. I have taken the liberty of adding a junk condition of halting before 2000.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed our by @Niteya it does not really matter which one you use, practically they are the same. I would like to point out, however, that you have a race condition in your code. According to [OpenMP memory model](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu9.html):

> if at least one thread reads from a memory unit and at least one
> thread writes without synchronization to that same memory unit,(...),
> then a data race occurs. If a data race occurs then the **result of the
> program is unspecified**.

To correct it you have to use atomic read/write operations. So, your code should be something like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(flag)
for(int i=0; i<=100000; ++i)
{        
    bool tmp_flag;
    #pragma omp atomic read acquire
    tmp_flag=flag;
    if(!tmp_flag)
    {
        if(element[i]  == 2000)
        {
            #pragma omp atomic write release
            flag=true;
        }
    }
}
```